# How to make \ a literal back slash using Regexp in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I am pretty new to Regexp and it seems that the `\` is used for meta characters. My problem is I want to search this string exactly `\"mediaType\":\"img\"`

Now I also want to dynamically put a variable in for img. So I want it to be something like this

```
new RegExp(`\"mediaType\":\"${variable}\"`)
```

How do I write this to make it work?

Comment: Use: `new Regex('\\\\"mediaType\\\\":\\\\"img\\\\"')`

Comment: `\ ` is an escape character in both javascript strings and regular expression. You have to escape your escape. Also, you don't need to escape `"` in regex (if that's what you're trying to do

Comment: @ctwheels I need the `"` as it is part of the string I am searching for

Comment: @anubhava it was only three \\\  if I did four it gave me two \\ and I only needed one, thank you for the help!

Comment: `RegExp` instead of `Regex`

Comment: @TaylorAustin then you should simply use `"mediaType":"${variable}"`, but honestly, I would use `"mediaType"\s*:\s*"{variable}"` instead as it takes into account the possibility of whitespace separating the two values (assuming this is possible and intended). Also, you should use the `.escape` function (click the link that your question has been marked a duplicate of). There's no need to escape the `"` since it has no special meaning in regex. If you need to escape it in javascript, however, you can do that, although I would simply use `'` instead

Comment: I think you misunderstood , I need the literal string \"mediaType\":\"img\", with those slashes in the string.

Answer (score 2):

You just want to use [`String.raw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw)

```js
const variable = 'text'
const regexp = new RegExp(String.raw `\"mediaType\":\"${variable}\"`)
console.log(regexp)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

```
function escapeRegEx(s) {
    return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
}

var expression = new RegExp('\\\\"mediaType\\\\":\\\\"' + escapeRegEx(variable) + '\\\\"');
// or, using a template literal:
var expression = new RegExp(`\\\\"mediaType\\\\":\\\\"${escapeRegEx(variable)}\\\\"`);
```

**Long answer:**

Besides being used for meta characters, backslash in regular expressions can be used to escape characters that would otherwise have meaning (like `*`, `$`, parentheses, and `\`). So the way to match a backslash in a regular expression is to add another one as an escape character: `\\`.

Taking that into account, the regular expression you want to end up with is `\\"mediaType\\":\\"img\\"`, and if you were using a regular expression literal that would be it. Unfortunately it gets a little more involved because you need to create an expression dynamically, you need to provide the expression as a string, which *also needs the backslashes escaped*. That adds a second layer of escaping, so you need to double up each of the `\` characters again, and you end up with `new RegExp('\\\\"mediaType\\\\":\\\\"img\\\\"')`.

Another complication is that you want the contents of `variable` to be matched literally, not interpreted as a regular expression. Unfortunately, there's no built-in way to automatically escape regular expressions in JavaScript, so you'll need to use one of the solutions in [Is there a RegExp.escape function in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3561493/2214). I used a slightly modified version of the accepted answer that defines it as a standalone function instead of adding it to the `RegExp` object. The exact solution doesn't matter, as long as you escape the dynamic part.

Comment: Alternatively keep the template literal: ``new RegExp(`\\\\"mediaType\\\\":\\\\"${ escapeRegex( variable ) }\\\\"`)`` to avoid confusion over `'`/`"`

Comment: @Bergi That's a good point, I used concatenation out of habit, but they did use a template literal in the question. I'll add that as an alternative.